# how to feed all methods with one instance of required class

Tags: asp.net, httprequest

there is a class that other classes use it in their methods . I want to give all methods just **one instance** of the class **during a request** .

update : saying **during a request** I **mean** : when a user makes a request to the server to load a webpage (**beginRequest**) , several events and methods would be called and raised . many of them need my class to save some data into a database . instead of **instantiating** my class in **each** method or page and making **several transactions** to the database , I want all methods to use just **one instance** that **buffers** those data and at **the end of** request **insert all** data into database **once** . and these **repeat** with the next request

Comment: Do you mean a Singelton? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern  or from P&P: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998426.aspx

Comment: @rene :I updated the question , I want all methods that require an instance of this class , use the same instance . but just during a request . I think singleton do the same but for all requests

Comment: What do you mean with "a request"? A specific method, once? A specific method, every time.. ?

Comment: Thanks, all clear now. I'd say you should go for a variation on the singleton.

Comment: @AndersHolmström : sounds good , can you give me a clue ? a link or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use per-request collection and using it create per-request singletone.

https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215202/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx

Comment: @JackSpector : thank you , I found this blog post http://bit.ly/8sjlZ . as I want to write this class in a class library , what do you think about using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext instead of HttpContext ?

Comment: Never worked with CallContext, but according to MSDN it's more related to thread storage. If you would use your class library in web-application and you don't require to save data more than per-request it's better idea to use HttpContext.Current.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Singleton pattern

From [P&P](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998426.aspx)

In some situations, a certain type of data needs to be available to all other objects in the application. In most cases, this type of data is also unique in the system. For example, a user interface can have only one mouse pointer that all applications must access. Likewise, an enterprise solution may interface with a single-gateway object that manages the connection to a specific legacy system

How do you make an instance of an object globally available and guarantee that only one instance of the class is created?

[Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx):

```
public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: is this possible to create a singleton in request-wide ?

Comment: Of course. Use HttpContext.Current.Items collection for storing singletone instance.